# How to change apache 2.2 htdocs folder out side of apache folder?

Tags: php, apache, apache-config, apache2.2

Hi I want to store my php project folder out side apache folder. How can I do that?

I changed my DocumentRoot "C:/sbnproj" like this.

after that I created one folder named mytest.php and write

```
<?php 

phpinfo();

?>
```

This code on that. But when I try to access http://localhost/

is working but when I type http://localhost/mytest.php is not working. it shows

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /mytest.php on this server.
```

Why this happening please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a trailing forward slash.

```
C:/sbnproj/
```

Also, check your paths... if your getting the root page it's working, make sure C:/sbnproj/foldername/ exists.

Comment: Hi I am sorry I forgot to change <Directory "C:/sbnproj">
now its working fine. Thanks.